# Sum of $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} (-1)^n\ln(1+\frac{1}{n})$

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms

Let's consider $$U = \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} (-1)^n\ln(1+\frac{1}{n})$$

Now,

$$U_N = \sum_{n=1}^{2N+1} (-1)^n \ln(\frac{n+1}{n}) = \sum_{k=1}^N \ln \frac{2k+1}{2k} - \sum_{k=0}^N \ln \frac{2k+2}{2k+1}$$

Using $\ln(ab)=\ln a + \ln b$, I obtain two telescoping products and I find

$$U_N = \ln \frac{2N+1}{2} - \ln (2N+2) = \ln \frac{2N+1}{4N+4} \to \ln \frac{1}{2} $$

Then $U = - \ln 2$.

Yet, using $\ln(\frac{a}{b}) = \ln a - \ln b$, and then Stirling formula, my teacher found with a lot of calculus

$$U = \ln \frac{2}{\pi}$$

Is the first method wrong or has the second one failed?

Comment: The product does not telescopes. The right result is the second, see the Wallis product https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product

Comment: Specifically, the signs go exactly the wrong way for the telescoping -- they add up instead of cancelling.

Comment: Oh right it does not telescope at all... I always forgot the basics! Thanks.

Comment: Try checking [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2050983/272831).